# How do I show time in the Y axis in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am currently trying to do a graph reflecting the time spent per phone call. I need to be specific in the amount of minutes each call is but can't seem to get the y-axis to reflect the values correctly. I have tried using seconds and breaking it down to minutes:seconds but can't get it right.

```
DURATION    Duration (Minutes)
3222    53 Min 42 Sec
2833    47 Min 13 Sec
2753    45 Min 53 Sec
2220    37 Min 0 Sec
2175    36 Min 15 Sec
2154    35 Min 54 Sec
1953    32 Min 33 Sec
1905    31 Min 45 Sec
1845    30 Min 45 Sec
1803    30 Min 3 Sec
1795    29 Min 55 Sec
1764    29 Min 24 Sec
1635    27 Min 15 Sec
1607    26 Min 47 Sec
1589    26 Min 29 Sec
1582    26 Min 22 Sec
1509    25 Min 9 Sec
1505    25 Min 5 Sec
1504    25 Min 4 Sec
1478    24 Min 38 Sec
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem. How did you tried? What was the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In column A, have the duration in seconds.

In column B, use this formula to convert it to fractions of a day: `=B2/3600/24`

Now format column B using this custom format, so it displays as desired: `m" min" s" sec"`

Be sure to include the double quotes as shown in my string; they mark the parts of the format string that should be shown literally.

Now you can use the formatted column in your graph.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table (it's a good practice).
2. Add a helper column (or replace your Duration(min) column) with the following formula
   `=TIME(,,[@Duration])`
3. Format your Time column as Time (cumulative hh:mm:ss, represented in the Type list as 37:30:55)
4. Create a bar chart with the Time column as your data series.
5. Format your horizontal axis for the time intervals you like.  For example, you could set up the following values:
   Min=0
   Max=0.0416666 (one hour)
   Major=0.0069444 (ten minutes)
   Minor=0.0006944 (one minute)
6. Format everything else to taste.

[image]

Since Excel uses serial time/date where `1=1 day=24 hours`, divide as appropriate for the increments you'd like.